# django event with date available=True, make available=False on event.date is today

Tags: django, django-models

I have a event model which works fine, but i need the boolean to switch to false once the event_date == today, so people cannot book old events

```
class Event(models.Model):
    event_date = models.DateField()
    start = models.ForeignKey(TimeSlots, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Slot Time', null=True)
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = u'Event'
        verbose_name_plural = u'Event'

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.event_date)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        url = reverse('admin:%s_%s_change' % (self._meta.app_label, self._meta.model_name), args=[self.pk])
        return u'<a href="%s">%s</a>' % (url, str(self.start))
```

i was thinking of something like this

```
def save(day, month, year):
        events = Event.objects.filter(date__day=day, date__month=month, date__year=year)
        for event in events:
            change.available = False
            change.save()
```

but it doesnt work without a self
, what can i use to do make the boolean switch to false when event_date==current_date ?

thanks

---

i taught that the solution was

> @property def available(self):
>       return self.event_date > timezone.now().date()

the problem is that, i still need to manually put the boolean true or false. But when i put the property def available,
the boolean field disapear in admin and old date as marked as non available as it should BUT, newer date cannot be put as unavailable, but i need to be able to set to future date(event) as unavailable :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that specific situation, there are several solutions, the one that you proposed will not work (or not have the desired effect).

Perhaps the simplest one, to mark all events that happen today as not available (`available=False`) would be to create a [management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-management-commands/) containing the code you provided, that would be executed daily by a `cronjob`. This way all events that happen on a given day would be marked as not available, regardless of their "status".

Other solution (that would only work if the availability only depends on the date, which does not seem to be the case) would be to remove the database column (`available = models.BooleanField(default=True)` ) and implement an object property like this:

```
@property
def available(self):
    return self.event_date > timezone.now().date()
```

Comment: i taught it was all good bu the problem is that, i still need to manually put the boolean true or false. But when i put the property def available,
the boolean field disappear in admin and old date are marked as non available as it should BUT, newer date cannot be put as unavailable, but i need to be able to set to future date(event) as unavailable :/

Comment: As I said in the answer "would only work if the availability only depends on the date, which does not seem to be the case". Since depends on other criteria as well, the other approach (having a cron job) will be a better fit for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You should use cron jobs for such tasks. You should write a function that deactivates events based on your condition event_date == today and than run this function with cron job at particular hour each day.

One of the simplest Django plugins for cron jobs is [django-crontab](https://github.com/kraiz/django-crontab). It's very easy to set it up and it has good docs.